# How to use groovy variable in jenkins sh command

Tags: git, shell, jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration

I am trying to use a groovy variable in my Jenkins file as shown below

```
def since='2018-06-01';
count = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git rev-list --all --count master --since="${since}"').trim();
```

The variable since is not evaluating in the Jenkins output.

```
+ git rev-list --all --count master --since=
[Pipeline] echo
```

Looks like I am doing something wrong in the syntax. Can some one help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to interpolate Groovy variable into the string you have to use double quotes instead (single quotes create `String`, while double quotes create `GString`):

```
count = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git rev-list --all --count master --since=\\\"${since}\\\"").trim();
```

Also, if you want to pass `--since="2018-06-01"` you will have to escape `"` and `\` like in the above example.

Updated code produces following git command:

```
+ git rev-list --all --count master --since="2018-06-01"
```